# Excel data extraction from column

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, column

I have data from hospital on patients deaths. The data is not arranged properly, the data is as in link below

All the dates should in either column DOA (H Column) or DOD (I Column) or MB (J Column) and the rest of text should arranged in a separate column. Can anyone please help me to clean this data, as I have more than 5000 observations.
[enter link description here](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables)

```
+-------+-----------+-------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------------------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| Sl.NO | District  | State P No  | Age In Years  | Sex     | Symptoms          | Co-Morbidities                                     | DOA              | DOD                             | MB Date    | Notes                 |
+=======+===========+=============+===============+=========+===================+====================================================+==================+=================================+============+=======================+
| 10    | X4        | 6553        | 53            | F       | Fever             |  Cold                                              |  Cough           | Thyroid disease                 | 10-06-2020 | 20-06-2020            |
+-------+-----------+-------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------------------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| 11    | X5        | 8872        | 62            | M       | Fever             | Diabetes Mellitus                                  | 16-06-2020       | 16-06-2020                      | 21-06-2020 |                       |
+-------+-----------+-------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------------------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| 12    | X5        | 8880        | 55            | M       | Pneumonia         |  Respiratory distress Obese,   Chronic Alcoholic   | 18-06-2020       | 20-06-2020                      | 21-06-2020 |                       |
+-------+-----------+-------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------------------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| 13    | X2        | 9149        | 70            | M       | Loss of Appetite  |  Weakness, Hypertension                            | 18-06-2020       | 18-06-2020                      | 21-06-2020 |                       |
+-------+-----------+-------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------------------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| 14    | X3        | 9150        | 46            | M       | Weakness          |  Convulsions, Hypertension                         | 17-06-2020       | 18-06-2020                      | 21-06-2020 |                       |
+-------+-----------+-------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------------------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| 15    | X4        | 7732        | 60            | Female  | Fever             |  Cough                                             |  Breathlessness  | uncontrolled Diabetes Mellitus  | 17-06-2020 | 22-06-2020            |
+-------+-----------+-------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------------------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| 16    | X5        | 9237        | 90            | M       | Asymptomatic      | Hypertension                                       |                  | 20-06-2020                      | 22-06-2020 | Died at his residence |
+-------+-----------+-------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------------------------------+------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: It looks like your data have comma-separated symptoms and/or co-morbidities in the source data. You should either produce the data using a different field separator, such as tab or pipe, or you should enclose the fields in those two columns with text identifier such as double-quotes. Preferably, do both. Then try to import the file again using "Data>Get & Transform Data>From Text/CSV" so you can control the options as you import. Double-clicking the file to open in Excel will cause you problems like this.

Comment: I have access to this excel file only. If it was a from text to data setup I would have done that as suggested by you. Thanks

Comment: Your link is not correct. It merely shows the table generator. After you generate the table on that page, copy the table to the clipboard and paste it into your question.  Then, in your question, format what you pasted as code.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sir I have updated or edited again, if it is properly visible please doe let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: @siri I see your data, but given that data, I don't understand what you want for a result.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I have updated the table again. Last table was not properly pasted. I hope now it in good shape. Thanks

Comment: @siri OK. The data sample is better. But I still don't understand what you want for a result.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sir I want to a separate coloums where I can have the extracted dates from these sets of rows, as we can see there are some texts under DOA coloumn DOD and MB coloumns. I want to have these data from each observations under three separate column.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I am not concerned about the text columns, if they can also be extracted into one one column they I am fine with that too,

Comment: @siri OK but what about the date columns?  Should they be moved to DOA and DOD, or DOD and MB?

Comment: Sir if they can be moved to same column they its better otherwise I can have a new column.

Comment: They can be moved anyplace, but you have to specify.  What do you mean by "same" column?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sir I want to have a column where the dates should be aligned in their respective column. For example in the first row, DOA colum has data of cough and DOD column has Thyroid disease as entered data. But the actual data has that is date of admission (DOA) and Date of Death (DOD) are moved to column MB date and Notes. So I want clean so that from each row I can extract the DOA and DOD. DOD>=DOA. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

I have assumed, based on your data sample, that when there is an error, it is because there are three co-morbidities that have been split on the commas.

That being the case, I have tested to see if the `DOD` column contains a date.

- if DOD contains a date, then

  - Concatentate the Co-Morbitides with DOA and DOD
  - Get the DOA date from the MB Date Column
  - Get the DOD date from the Notes Column
  - Set the MB date to null

If that logic doesn't work for all, or if it is in error, it can be easily changed.

All the processing magic occurs in the arguments to the `Table.Group` function

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],

//Replace any blanks ("") with null for easier processing down the road
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Sl.NO", "District", "State P No", "Age In Years", "Sex", "Symptoms", "Co-Morbidities", "DOA", "DOD", "MB Date", "Notes"}),

//Group the table by the first six columns
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Replaced Value", {"Sl.NO", "District", "State P No", "Age In Years", "Sex", "Symptoms"}, {

//Extract the columns to be processed using the logic shown
        {"Co-Morbidities", each 
            if Value.Is([DOD]{0}, type datetime)
                then [#"Co-Morbidities"]{0}
                else Text.Combine({[#"Co-Morbidities"]{0},[DOA]{0}, [DOD]{0}},", "), type text},
        {"DOA", each 
            if Value.Is([DOD]{0}, type datetime)
                then DateTime.Date([DOA]{0})
                else if [DOA]{0} = null then null 
                else DateTime.Date([#"MB Date"]{0}), type date},
        {"DOD", each 
            if Value.Is([DOD]{0}, type datetime)
                then DateTime.Date([DOD]{0})
                else DateTime.Date([Notes]{0}), type date},
        {"MB Date", each 
                if Value.Is([DOD]{0}, type datetime)
                    then DateTime.Date([#"MB Date"]{0})
                    else null, type date},
        {"Notes", each 
                if Value.Is([Notes]{0}, type datetime)
                    then null 
                    else [Notes]{0}}
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

**Results**
[image]

Comment: Sir Can I have your mail Id. As I am facing some errors. I will mail you the data. Please sir it my research work. Please help me out.

Comment: @siri I do not post my email on public forums. *facing some errors* is not helpful in troubleshooting, but probably either you did not enter the code correctly, or your data is not consistent with what you posted.

Comment: May be ! As I didn't post entire data it may not be consistent with the sampled one. reddy.srikanth033@gmail.com is my mail id sir. So please ping me. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in stages (cause you are going to have to check this)!  This is mainly because your example only shows 2 dates and odds are there is missing data.  As if it's not just as simple as fixing a spreadseet.

[image]

Original data is in A2:k8.  DOA Column H and DOD Column I.

```
Cell L2 =ISNUMBER(SEARCH("2020",H2))
Cell M2 =ISNUMBER(SEARCH("2020",I2))
```

True: Date is good.  False: No date.  Error in data entry.

```
Cell N2 =IF(AND(NOT($L2),NOT($M2)),G2&", "&H2&", "&I2,"")
Cell O2 =IF(AND(NOT($L2),NOT($M2)),K2,IF(H2<>"",H2,""))
Cell P2 =IF(AND(NOT($L2),NOT($M2)),K2,I2)
Cell Q2 =IF(AND(NOT($L2),NOT($M2)),"",J2)
Cell R2 =IF(AND(NOT($L2),NOT($M2)),"",IF(K2<>"",K2,""))
```

Use existing data if correct, otherwise move inappropriate data to appropriate column.

Make backup.  Input formulas. Check, check, check.  Convert to values & delete bad columns.